# How is SCRIPT_NAME dangerous in PHP?

Tags: php

I am using the line below in my php blog site, how is that a danger ?

```
<form action="<?php echo $SCRIPT_NAME. "?id=" . $validentry; ?>" method="post">
```

I have `register_global off` and `magic_quotes_gpc()` also off.
I am using php 5.2.
I tried `$_SERVER['php_self']`, but that didn't work.

Comment: `$_SERVER['php_self']` didn't work because you wrote the key in lowercase.

Comment: Where does `$validentry` come from? If it's user-supplied input, or comes from a database without verifying the contents, you need to `urlencode()` it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SCRIPT_NAME` and `PHP_SELF` mostly contain the same value. Both contain the webserver-normalized version of `REQUEST_URI` (that is, relative path parts removed).

Your actual security issue here is not using [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars). And as said before, just use the correct key case to output `PHP_SELF`:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8") . $validentry ...
```

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't seem to pose any danger, but it suggests that you have `register_globals` On (which, if you are not really really careful is probably dangerous). Set `register_globals` to Off in your configuration file and use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` or, preferably `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, see also [this page on the PHP Manual regarding the `$_SERVER` superglobal](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), and [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#102734):

> $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] =>
>   /admin/products.php (virtual path)
>   $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] =>
>   /admin/products.php/someExtraStuff
>   (virtual path)
>
> SCRIPT_NAME is defined in the CGI 1.1
>   specification, PHP_SELF is created by
>   PHP itself. See
>   http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/qt/_SERVER_PHP.htm
>   for tests.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this works in PHP5.2 unless you have defined `$SCRIPT_NAME` yourself.
The right code should be `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']`, in this case.
 `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is not user controllable.
`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is user controllable.

Comment: This answer is better suited as a comment, as it is not an answer to the original question...

Comment: `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` is defined in CGI SAPIs.